# react usestate Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I fix this 'Too many re-renders' error ? 
I'm using try, catch method, useState, setState react hooks. 
I'm trying to get data from api and print on web.
Error occurs here : setEmoticonThm(newEmoticonThms) 
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```js
const [emoticonThm, setEmoticonThm] = useState([]);
```

```js
const getToken = async () => {
  try {
    const emoticon = await axios.get(`${process.env.EMOTICON_ENDPOINT}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: accessToken
      }
    })
    let newEmoticonThms = []
    emoticon.data.emoticonPacks.map( (emoticon) => {
      newEmoticonThms.push({
        id: emoticon.id,
        image:url + emoticon.image
      })  
    })
    setEmoticonThm(newEmoticonThms)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

```js
const onClickSticker = () => {
  getToken()
  handleKeyboardOpen()
}

return (
 ...
 <Sticker onClick={onClickSticker}/>
 <TabContainer>
      {emoticonThm.map((emoticon, index) => {
           return (
                <EmoticonThmButton 
                     key={index}
                     onClick={setSelectedThm(index)}
                 >
                      <EmoticonThmImage
                           key={index}
                           onClick={onEmoticonClick}
                           src={img}
                      />
                 </EmoticonThmButton>
           )
        })}
 </TabContainer>
)
```

I added my code.
How can I get it right? TT

Comment: Where do you call `getToken`? Can you provide the full code, as this is not reproducible.

Comment: @SinanYaman I edited the code. thanks for your comment.

Comment: Where are you using the `emoticonThm` state?

Comment: You didn't provide a reproducible code I'm afraid. Now we have to see the `handleKeyboardOpen` function? Do you use `setEmoticonThm` anywhere else?

Comment: I added the codes. handleKeyboardOpen func is simple.  It just changes state.

Comment: Instead of  `onClick={setSelectedThm(index)}` do `onClick = {()=>setSelectedThm(index)}`

Comment: What does `setSelectedThm` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `onClick={setSelectedThm(index)}` do `onClick = {()=>setSelectedThm(index)}`

`onClick={setSelectedThm(index)}` is causing too many rerenders, as the function immediately gets called on the rendering phase. Instead of directly calling the function, you should pass the closure that wraps the function to delay its execution.